# why my SensorManager.getRotationMatrix always return false?

Tags: java, android, sensors

I try so many times by using "switch" or "for" syntax to changing the codes, but it always appears nothing, 90% I would think it is because SensorManager.getRotationMatrix return false, but why? how can I fix it? I have tried to do the other solutions that in Stack but none of them works..I am using Android Studio and run on my samsung which API is 19, my SDK is 21.

BTW, I use both permissions

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I am so confused, and hoping someone could help me!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SensorEventListener {

TextView tv0;
TextView tv1;
TextView tv2;
TextView tv3;
TextView tv4;
SensorManager mSensorManager;
Sensor mAccelerometerSensor;
Sensor mMagneticSensor;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Layout
    LinearLayout lmain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    lmain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    //Title
    tv0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label0);
    tv0.setText("\n COMPASS\n");
    tv0.setTextSize(30);


    //SensorManager
    SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    //Declaring the sensor (AccelerometerSensor & MagneticSensor)
    mAccelerometerSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mMagneticSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

    //Initialize the Sensor Event Listener (AccelerometerSensor & MagneticSensor)
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mMagneticSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);




    //setOrientation
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label1);
    tv1.setText("\n This is Orientation \n");
    tv1.setTextSize(20);

    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label2);
    tv2.setTextSize(15);

    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label3);
    tv3.setTextSize(15);

    tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label4);
    tv4.setTextSize(15);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


    float[] mGravity = new float[3];
    float[] mGeomagnetic = new float[3];
    float azimuth;
    float pitch;
    float roll;

    if (event.sensor.getType() == event.sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
            mGravity[i]=event.values[i];
    }

    if (event.sensor.getType() == event.sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
            mGravity[i]=event.values[i];
    }

    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float[] R = new float[9];
        float[] I = new float[9];
        float[] orientation;
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, null, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            orientation = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            azimuth = orientation[0]; 
            pitch = orientation[1];
            roll = orientation[2];
            tv2.setText("azimuth: " + Float.toString(azimuth));
            tv3.setText("pitch: " + Float.toString(pitch));
            tv4.setText("roll: " + Float.toString(roll));
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

}

Comment: FINE/COARSE location are for GPS...

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't work after I delete them both..

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Did you manage to solve this?